# Android app and serialization/deserialization efficiency?

Tags: java, android, serialization, deserialization

An initial search didn't render quite the results I expected, and Google didn't help much, either. So here goes...

I'm working on an app where I'm serializing objects to a file. There's really no need, because of what the app is, to serialize more than one object at a time (because objects will generally be created one at a time).

However, *deserializing* is where I have the question.

What I'd like to do is be able to deserialize a **specific** object, based on an ID.

In other words, let's say I have a file of serialized objects with the following data:

1, Montgomery Burns, M, 100
2, Homer Simpson, M, 38
3, Waylon Smithers, M, 44
4, Krusty the Clown, M, 60
5, Marge Simpson, F, 38
...etc...

And let's say that I only want to get the second object (for example's sake, the ID is 2).

Based on the reading and research I've done, there's no way to get a *specific* object in this manner. If I understand correctly, I would have to read my entire serialized object file (let's call it data.ser) into memory (say, an array or list of deserialized objects), and then iterate over it until I find what I'm looking for. Is that correct?

I don't have a problem doing this, it just seems terribly inefficient.

Though I don't anticipate my app's users having hundreds or thousands of objects, so this all may be irrelevant, I'm just wondering if I'm understanding this correctly. It's mainly for personal use and self-learning about Android.

I'm not against using an embedded database. I'd like to avoid it for now, just to keep the app size down.

So am I understanding this correctly? I haven't actually seen a way to retrieve a specific object, other than what I illustrated above. My understanding is that the ***only*** way to do it in Java is to iterate over the objects.

Comment: use **GSON**   that would help

Comment: The file would have to be in memory, at least initially, for any program to know the contents of the file.  I'm sure there are libraries built to querying a file or even making your own shouldn't be too involved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'm working on an app where I'm serializing objects to a file.

I am going to assume, from the rest of your question, that you are referring to Java serialization. AFAICT, that has been obsolete for over a decade, and I would never recommend that anyone spend more than 10 seconds considering it as a storage option. But, you are certainly welcome to use it.

> Based on the reading and research I've done, there's no way to get a specific object in this manner.

That's because you decided to put them all in one file. The unit of serialization is the top-level object.

You are certainly welcome to store them each in their own file, with a filename that enables you to identify the proper file to deserialize when needed.

Or, you are welcome to maintain an "index" (e.g., `HashMap`) that is serialized separately, where you maintain enough information to identify the file representing the object itself. The idea is that you keep the "index" small enough that maintaining it is relatively cheap.

> (for example's sake, the ID is 2)

So, have `thingy-2.ser` that contains the serialized object with ID 2, so you can deserialize that one object.

> I don't have a problem doing this, it just seems terribly inefficient.

Your real inefficiency is in writing, not reading. If you change one byte in one object, you have to write out **the entire collection**. Reading is cheap by comparison.

Comment: I need to give you a thumb's up here! This is great information. What do you recommend in lieu of serialization? You're correct that I'm using Java, and I'm writing an Android app, so I'm looking for a way to store the information that is efficient to write and to read.

Comment: @MJR: Well, I don't know enough about your data model to give you a solid recommendation. SQLite (with or without an ORM layer) is a typical choice, as you get a full SQL database for random access to your data. There are alternative databases for local (e.g., Realm), hosted (e.g., Parse), or both (e.g., Couchbase/Couchbase Mobile). If you want the feel of serialization, JSON or possibly FlatBuffers, as they at least are cross-language (as opposed to Java serialization).

Comment: My data model is essentially three fields. One is a UUID that acts as an ID, and two other string fields. I'd considered using Derby, or another "embedded" database. At this point, I think the size increase would be negligible, considering the overall size of the app will be relatively small anyway. I'll have to check out Realm. Thanks for all your help! How do I award you points??

Comment: @MJR: "I'd considered using Derby, or another "embedded" database" -- I do not know why you would use Derby as opposed to SQLite. SQLite is part of Android; Derby is not (though it probably can run on Android). SQLite is also going to be a fair bit faster and is more "standard" (i.e., more stuff written about using it), compared to Derby. You're certainly welcome to use it, if you want, but it is definitely non-traditional. "How do I award you points?" -- that comes as part of accepting the answer. :-)

Comment: Interesting. Thanks, again. I had no idea that SQLite was "built in". I will definitely look into that. At this stage of development, it shouldn't be difficult to add/modify my design pattern(s) as needed to incorporate SQLite. And consider your answer accepted! You've been quite helpful!

Comment: your idea for using SQLite was BRILLIANT. I'm working through what I think are a couple of minor issues, but so far it's been brilliant! I wish I could give you more points.